# How to edit a particular sheet using Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I created a form that has list of items to be selected. I also created a spreadsheet that has a couple of sheets that correspond to the elements in the form. 
I wanted users to select a category and fill data on the form for that category so that the data will be saved in the particular sheet associated to the category. Is it possible to edit a particular sheet on Google's Spreadsheet based on a selection Google Form?

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms doesn't edit data in Google Sheets, instead they send responses.
Responses sent to a Google spreadsheet could be updated but should be enabled the option "Allow users to edit responses".

By the other hand, Google Forms and Google Sheets don't have a built-in feature to send responses to specific sheets based one answer.

One alternative is to use and combine built-in Google Sheets features and functions like:

- arrays
- Functions like QUERY, FIlTER, etc.
- Pivot Table reports

Another alternative is to use Google Apps Script.

In the right panel of this page there is a section of related questions that could help you to refine your question or to post another one more specific.

---

**References**

- [Edit form responses after submitting - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183417?hl=en)
- [Using arrays in Google Sheets - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)
- [Google spreadsheets function list - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)
- [Overview of pivot table reports - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272898?hl=en)
- [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this link

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737?hl=en

I suppose you should not edit the spreadsheet directly. Alternatively you need to edit the Form and the changes will be made to spreadsheets automatically.

Comment: This link is only for designing the form. What I wanted is selecting one of the sheets based on a choice on the form.